# Выполнение sql скрипта с условием (firebird)

Tags: sql, firebird

Есть скрипт.
Который нужно прогнать только при условии что
поле таблицы **x** имеет значение **у** равное **z**.

Иначе не выполнять.
Программа прогоняющая скрипт этого делать не умеет.
Какое условие поместить в начало скрипта что бы оно повлияло на выполнение дальнейшего текста?

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, следует писать процедуру, включить в нее скрипт, а первым оператором сделать SELECT Y INTO....FROM X. Далее - через IF.